# Want to detect date columns and convert them into datetime64 dtype format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date1': ['20200422', '20200422.0', '20200501', '0'],
    'Date2': ['15/05/2023', '0', '20230520', '25/06/2023'],
    'Other1': ['Text1', 'Text2', 'Text3', 'Text4'],
    'Other2': [10, 20, 30, 0]
})
```

I want code to detect only Date1 and Date2 and convert these two column dtype to datetime64 and their format to dd/mm/yyyy. It can convert those 0s in Date1 and Date2 to NaN.

Answer (score 1):

If want convert `Date1` and `Date2` columns to datetimes use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'].replace('\.0','',regex=True), errors='coerce')
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
print (df)
       Date1      Date2 Other1  Other2
0 2020-04-22 2023-05-15  Text1      10
1 2020-04-22        NaT  Text2      20
2 2020-05-01 2023-05-20  Text3      30
3        NaT 2023-06-25  Text4       0
```

If there are 2 formats in `Date2` is possible use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'].str.replace('\.0','',regex=True), errors='coerce')

d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'], errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y')
d2 = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'], errors='coerce', format='%Y%m%d')
df['Date2'] = d1.fillna(d2)
print (df)
       Date1      Date2 Other1  Other2
0 2020-04-22 2023-05-15  Text1      10
1 2020-04-22        NaT  Text2      20
2 2020-05-01 2023-05-20  Text3      30
3        NaT 2023-06-25  Text4       0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to detect the dates columns automatically, you can use a custom function:

```
from functools import reduce

def date_detect(s, formats=None):
    try:
        s1 = s.str.replace(r'\.0*', '', regex=True)
    except AttributeError:
        s1 = s
    if formats is None:
        s2 = pd.to_datetime(s1, errors='coerce')
    else:
        s2 = reduce(lambda a,b: a.fillna(b), 
                    [pd.to_datetime(s1, format=f, errors='coerce')
                     for f in formats])
    if s2.notna().any():
        return s2
    return s

out = df.apply(date_detect, formats=['%d/%m/%Y', '%Y%m%d'])
```

Output:

```
       Date1      Date2 Other1  Other2
0 2020-04-22 2023-05-15  Text1      10
1 2020-04-22        NaT  Text2      20
2 2020-05-01 2023-05-20  Text3      30
3        NaT 2023-06-25  Text4       0
```

dtypes:

```
Date1     datetime64[ns]
Date2     datetime64[ns]
Other1            object
Other2             int64
dtype: object
```